# insertInto method returns NPE exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-2.1

I am trying to create an external table to read data from partitioned parquet files in hdfs. To do so, I am creating first the external table using this string:

```
spark.sql(
  "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.mytable (col1 int)\n" +
  "PARTITIONED BY (yyyy int, mm int)\n" +
  "STORED AS PARQUET\n" +
  "LOCATION 'hdfs://group/poc/mydata'"
)
```

being spark a SparkSession created with these two options:

```
spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .config(sparkConfigurations)
      .getOrCreate()

def sparkConfigurations = {
    cfg.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    cfg.set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonrestrict")
  }
```

And then, I am trying to insert data in this table from a dataframe:

```
df.write
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .insertInto("mydb.mytable")
```

being df a dataframe with same schema than hive table.

This last insertInto raises a NullPointerException error, without more information.

Worst of all, is if I run the first CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE code from hive, the insertInto method starts to work well.

PS: I cannot use the saveAsTable method because I am using spark 2.1.0 and this method is not supported until version 2.2.0.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please include the traceback.

Comment: It returns a NullPointerException, so there is not too much to do with the log. I have already digging on it, and the problem happens just when I explained

Comment: And how should know which component throws NPE?

Comment: the insertInto method returns a NPE

Comment: That doesn't really narrow things down much.

Comment: Of course, the error is quite complicated. As I say, if I create the external table from hive, the insertInto method works as expected. But if I create the external table at runtime with spark, the insertInto method returns the NPE. Everything points a bug, but I asked if someone found a workaround for this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem...

When I create the hive table with spark.sql it adds some extra literature in form of TBLPROPERTIES. Inside these properties, there were the partition columns I was using, but in uppercase, where the column names are in lower case.

That was returning a NPE, so once I have changed everything to be in lower case it started to work.